# Problem with pre-beta sdk - even after reinstalling SDK 3.2

Tags: iphone, beta, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload the binary for a new app, but always get this errormessage:
"The binary you uploaded was invalid. A pre-release beta version of the SDK was used to build the application."

I know several people have asked a similar question, but I've tried all suggestions from the answers there without success.

I used the XCode 4.0 beta 3 during development, and I've tried using it to compile for earlier releases (3.0, 3.1.3, 3.2 etc...)

I've also tried downgrading to SDK 3.2, as well as removing 4.0 beta 3 and then installing SDK 3.2 as a fresh install.

It seems to me that there might be some parameter in the "Edit Project Settings" that is sticking from the use of 4.0 beta 3, but I've tried to identify them without success.

My last option seem to be a complete reinstall of both OS and SDK. Is there something else I might try first?

Comment: Because we are under NDA for pre-release software, I cannot discuss this here.  However, I do suggest reading through Apple's Developer Forums (or asking there), because this topic has been covered before: https://devforums.apple.com/community/iphone/40beta/installation

Answer (score 1):

It now works. I'm not sure which steps can be excluded, or if they are at all related, but it worked for me after doing this:

1. Uninstall SDK 4.0 beta 3
2. Reboot
3. Install SDK 3.2.2
4. Compile for 3.1.3
5. Delete Build folder
6. Run "Build" not "Build and Go".

I'm pretty sure it wouldn't be enough with the last step alone, as I've tried similar approaches, but I'm not sure what steps can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the build directory (which seems to be more effective than just a clean), and rebuild?